# DataTables 1.10 parse aadata from json failed on HTML5

Tags: php, json, html, datatables

I'm currently working with HTML5, so I need to use DataTabels 1.10

The problem is the ajaxsouce failed to parse the json from the php file I have.
Actually it worked fine, and still works fine with my project on DataTables 1.9.4 and HTML4, but somehow I failed using it with DataTables 1.10 and HTML5

this is how I call my ajax :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "ajax": "viewobat1.php"
} );
```

} );

I've changed to `"sAjaxSource": "viewobat1.php"` too, but wont work either

this is what I do in `viewobat.php` to get json

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM obat";
$hasil=mysql_query($sql);
print("{\"aaData\":[");
$tambahan="\n";
$no=0;
while($cetak=mysql_fetch_array($hasil))
    {$no++;
    $no;
        $idobat=$cetak[0];
        $tanggalmasuk=$cetak[1];
        $namaobat=$cetak[2];
        $jenis=$cetak[3];
        $macam=$cetak[4];
        $keterangan=$cetak[5];
        $stok=$cetak[6];

    print($tambahan."[\"$no\","."\"$idobat\","."\"$tanggalmasuk\","."\"$namaobat\","."\"$jenis\","."\"$macam\",
    "."\"$keterangan\","."\"$stok\]");
    $tambahan=",\n";

    }
    print("\n]}\n");
?>
```

I dont see any problem to my json, PHP is returning a valid JSON array
 [image: output]

but the data won't show on table,

am I missing something ?

**~EDITED~**

I've changed the way to get the required data with the server-side tutorial from datatables.net ---> [SERVER SIDE](http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html)

my code come like this,

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$table = 'obat';

$primaryKey = 'idobat';
$columns = array(
    array( 'db' => 'idobat', 'dt' => 0 ),
    array( 'db' => 'tanggalmasuk',  'dt' => 1 ),
    array( 'db' => 'namaobat',   'dt' => 2 ),
    array( 'db' => 'jenis',     'dt' => 3 ),
    array( 'db' => 'macam', 'dt' => 4 ),
    array( 'db' => 'keterangan',  'dt' => 5 ),
    array( 'db' => 'stok',   'dt' => 6 ),
);

$sql_details = array(
    'user' => 'root',
    'pass' => '',
    'db'   => 'medical',
    'host' => 'localhost'
);

require( 'js\DataTables-1.10.2\examples\server_side\scripts\ssp.class.php' );

echo json_encode(
    SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
);
```

and of course... PHP is returning valid data again

[image: sample2]

I called ajax the exact same way as the tutorial too...

and of course... the data still won't come out in my table...

so again, am I missing something ?? (O_o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeey... I found my answer (*it's weird answer*)

just changed my script to
-->

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

and it did all the trick... it's weird, isn't it...? i know..

I dont know why should I use CDN that required http instead and failed call it from my own server using PATH_TO_FOLDER method,

but it works anyway,
reference from question --> [cant get datatables net working with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25357724/cant-get-datatables-net-working-with-javascript)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> department.php (server side)

```
<?php
    $qry="select dept_id,dept_name from tb_department ";
    $result=mysqli_query($connection,$qry);           
    $data=array();
    $i=0;
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
         $data[] = $row;
    }
    $response = array(
        'aaData' => $data,
        'iTotalRecords' => count($data),
        'iTotalDisplayRecords' => count($data)
    );
    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

> index.php (client side)

```
 <table id="example"  class="table table-bordered table-striped  table-hover">
     <thead>
         <tr>
             <th>Department ID </th>
             <th>Department Name</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tfoot>
         <tr>
              <th>Department ID </th>
              <th>Department Name</th>
         </tr>
       </tfoot>
  </table>

  <script >
     $(document).ready(function(){
     var table= $('#example').DataTable( {
     ajax: {
          url: 'department.php',
          dataSrc: 'aaData',
          method:'POST'
     },
     columns: [
          { data: 'dept_id' },
          { data: 'dept_name' }
     ],
   });
   </script>
```

This code work for me....!
Using dataTable 1.10 , jQuery 2.1.0